# Acessing selected points using lasso

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I was going through the D3.js plottings. I found a way to select the points in a scatter plot and highlight them in the plot from this awesome blog post [here](http://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/511c5b658c405ad68941)

I want to further extend this and make a list of the classes of the selected points along with highlighting them.

If I selected 4 points corresponding to `setosa` and 2 points of `virginica` I want to get a array like this.

```
[[setosa, 1.2, 3.4],
[setosa, 1.2, 3.4],
[setosa, 1.2, 3.4],
[setosa, 1.2, 3.4],
[virginica, 1.2, 3.4],
[virginica, 1.2, 3.4]]
```

I want this to happen at the end of lasso. I played around a little bit with lasso_end function but I was not able to achieve it. How can this be achieved.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposed answer here will give you an array of objects. From that, for having an array of arrays (as you want) you just need some minor adjustments, which you can do yourself.

First, let's create an empty array:

```
var mySelectedArray = [];
```

Then, inside the `lasso_end`, let's get the selected elements, which are actually one array with an inner array of DOM elements:

```
var selected = lasso.items().filter(function(d) {
    return d.selected===true
});
```

Then, using that array, let's get their data, pushing them to our empty array:

```
selected[0].forEach(function(d){
    mySelectedArray.push(d3.select(d).datum())
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks, select the dots and have a look at the console: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/raw/53ae382aa8fd2ea751683e946bc50b19/03ef4083122568306237493afbdc4e442f2398f8/

---

PS: you can also simply use a D3 `selectAll` instead of `lasso.items()`and filter for `selected: true`, which gives you a simple array.

Comment: But when I am doing the  same on another data with more points the console output is `unavailable`

Comment: Well, it's impossible for me to say what's going on. The best idea here is posting a *new* question, with all the relevant details.